# Having issues with static file storage when deploying a django 4.2 project

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I am having issues with deploying a django 4.2 project.  When I push it to Heroku I get an application error that reads, "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail."

When I inspect the logs I believe the issue is boiling down to this, " django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: STATICFILES_STORAGE/STORAGES are mutually exclusive."

I believe I have done something wrong in my settings.py file as the tutorial I was watching used an older version of Django and there were updates made to the syntax on define storage in settings.py in this version of Django.  However, I am confused because I am not using "STATICFILES_STORAGE" anywhere.  I tried to follow along with the tutorial while also reading the new documentation to handle this correctly.  I must have used some old syntax, but am unsure where I did that.

Here is my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = (removed for security purposes)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'nameless-caverns-49658.herokuapp.com',
    ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'affiliate',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

"""
Commented out because this is old syntax recommended by the video.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
"""

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

And here is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.7.2
dj-database-url==2.0.0
Django==4.2.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.6
python-decouple==3.8
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.6.3
tzdata==2023.3
whitenoise==6.4.0
```

Please let me know if you see any issues here that may be leading to the errors I am receiving!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From [django-heroku](https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/#description) docs, you can disable automatic configuration for staticfiles. Worked for me.

```
django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In short:**
Wherever you have a line saying:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

add after it:

```
config = locals()
config['STORAGES']['staticfiles'] = config['STATICFILES_STORAGE']
del config['STATICFILES_STORAGE']
```

**Longer story:**
Try running the code in the debugger and view the settings values.
Likely both `'STATICFILES_STORAGE' in dir(mod)` and `'STORAGES' in dir(mod)` are `True`, which means that you are importing both settings from your `self.SETTINGS_MODULE`.

[image: Screenshot with source code and debugger stopped on a breakpoint]

And then you might also discover that your django-heroku is setting `STATICFILES_STORAGE` here:
[image: core.py of django-heroku, line 102]

That's why we need to move this setting from `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and add to `STORAGES -> staticfiles`.